# Lectura de archivos

Tags: c

espero que se encuentren bien.

Estoy intentando leer varios archivos tipo DAT al mismo tiempo sin tener que repetir la estructura While con una cadena de caracteres, pero veo que no lo permite, quisiera saber si existe otra forma de leer esos tres archivos.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct{
    int precipitacion,
        velocidad,
        temperatura,
        radiacion;
}Estructura;

int main()
{
    
    int p,i=0,j=0;
    Estructura semana;
    char *nombre_archivos[]={"enea_s1_marzo_2020.dat","palogrande_s1_marzo_2020.dat","chipre_s1_marzo_2020.dat"};
    //FILE *manejador_archivo0 = NULL;
    //manejador_archivo0 = fopen("enea_s1_marzo_2020.dat", "rb+");
    //FILE *manejador_archivo1 = NULL;
    //manejador_archivo1 = fopen("palogrande_s1_marzo_2020.dat", "rb+");
    //FILE *manejador_archivo2 = NULL;
    //manejador_archivo2 = fopen("chipre_s1_marzo_2020.dat","rb+");
    
    if (manejador_archivo0 == NULL || manejador_archivo1 == NULL || manejador_archivo2 == NULL) {
        printf("El archivo no fue abierto Èxitosamente\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        for (int z = 3; z < 3; ++z)
        {
            printf("\n-------------------Archivo 1--------------------");
            fread(&semana, sizeof(Estructura), 1, nombre_archivos[z]);
            while (!feof(nombre_archivos[z])){
                printf("\nDIA [%d] HORA[%d] \n\nPrecipitación: %d \nVelocidad: %d \nTemperatura: %d\nRadiación: %d\n",i+1,j+1,semana.precipitacion, semana.radiacion, semana.temperatura, semana.velocidad);                    
                fread(&semana, sizeof(Estructura), 1, nombre_archivos[z]);
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }   
    }
    fclose(manejador_archivo2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema: Procesar en forma simple información dividida entre varios archivos.

Solución: Crear una función de lectura que automáticamente abra el siguiente archivo al terminarse el archivo actual.

Implementación: Una función `zread` igual a `fread`, excepto que en lugar de pasar un `FILE`, pasamos un arreglo de nombres de archivo.

La función declara dos variables estáticas (conservan su valor entre llamadas). Una variable es `index`, que se usa para recorrer la lista de archivos. La otra el `file`, que contiene el puntero al archivo actualmente siendo leido.

En cada llamada, la función intenta leer del archivo actual. Si esto falla, se cierra el archivo actual, se avanza `index` en uno y se comprueba que todavía haya nombres de archivo en la lista. En tal caso, se abre un nuevo archivo y se reintenta la lectura.

Cuando se agota la llista de archivos, `index` se reinicializa en -1, lo que permite reiniciar el proceso con otra lista de archivos.

La función retorna el valor entregado por el último `fread`.

```
size_t zread(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, char* archivos[]) {
    static int index = -1;
    static FILE* file;
    if (index == -1) {
        index = 0;
        file = fopen(archivos[index], "r");
    }
    int reads = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, file);
    while (reads <= 0) {
        index++;
        fclose(file);
        if (archivos[index]) {
            file = fopen(archivos[index], "r");
            reads = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, file);
        } else {
            index = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return reads;
}
```

Tal como está definida, la función lee archivos con cualquier contenido. En este ejemplo, lee dos simples archivos e imprime su contenido.

```
int main()
{
    char linea[10];
    char* archivos[] = {"archivo1.txt", "archivo2.txt", NULL};
    int reads;
    while (reads = zread(linea, 10, 1, archivos)) {
        printf(linea);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Gracias, ¿Si quisiera hacerlo con el fwrite?

Comment: @MrHakle. Una vez leída la línea, puedes hacer lo que quieras con ella, incluso usarla con `fwrite`.